# How do I avoid checking everything with a different If using for loops?

Tags: c++

In C++, how do I avoid walls of ifs using for loops?
stackoverflow is requesting more text soo...
Code Example:

```
if(masiv[0][0] == 'X'){
    masiv[0][0] = '1';
}
if(masiv[0][1] == 'X'){
    masiv[0][1] = '2';
}
if(masiv[0][2] == 'X'){
    masiv[0][2] = '3';
}
if(masiv[1][0] == 'X'){
    masiv[1][0] = '4';
}
if(masiv[1][1] == 'X'){
    masiv[1][1] = '5';
}
if(masiv[1][2] == 'X'){
    masiv[1][2] = '6';
}
if(masiv[2][0] == 'X'){
    masiv[2][0] = '7';
}
if(masiv[2][1] == 'X'){
    masiv[2][1] = '8';
}
if(masiv[2][2] == 'X'){
    masiv[2][2] = '9';
}
```

Comment: This question is better suited for your teaching staff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
  for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
    if (masiv[y][x] == 'X') {
      masiv[y][x] = '1' + 3 * y + x;
    }
  }
}
```

Some explanation follows.

The following pattern is repeating:

```
if (masiv[...][...] == 'X') {
  masiv[...][...] = '...';
}
```

Because it is repeating, we put it to the body of the `for` loop.

We need 2 `for` loops, because the first and the second indexes in `masiv[...][...]` go over all possible values independently, and each variation is present. We will use a separate loop variable for each index, thus it becomes `masiv[y][x]`.

The lower limit for `y` is 0 (inclusive) and the upper limit for `y` is 3 (exclusive), hence the `for` line looks like: `for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {`. Similarly for `x`.

We need a different character after the `masiv[y][x] =`. Since digits are next to each other in the ASCII table (e.g. `'5' + 3 == '8'`). we use an expression like `'1' + ...y... + ...x...`. The actual value starts from `'1'` in the beginning, and it increases by 1 as `x` increases, and it increases by 3 when `y` increases. Thus it's `'1' + 3 * y + x`.

Comment: This is very straightforward for anyone who has experience in C or C++. but the OP is clearly very new. I'm not sure the question is suitable for SO, but if you're answering, some explanation rather than just code would make this a better answer.

Comment: @Chris: Done, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Well done.